# Subject verb agreement error

Tags: american-english, british-english, subject-verb-agreement, indian-english

> 1. Slow and steady win the race.

or

> 2. Slow and steady wins the race.

I know that 'wins' is the correct answer but can anyone explain me why? And why 'win' can't be filled there and where is the subject in the sentence because 'Slow and steady' is an adjective and adjective can't be the subject of a sentence.

Comment: Adjective phrases can function as subject, for example "Too big for your boots is what you are".

Answer (score 1):

First variant ("win") can be correct too, if you want to refer to "slow" and "steady" individually.

Second is better suited, because "slow" and "steady" are combined into a single "strategy". So the phrase, from this point of view, can be re-written as:

> Good strategy wins the race.